# Best Practice to Load Class in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala (and functional programming as well) and I'm developing a plugin based application to learn and study.
I've cretead a trait to be the interface of a plugin. So when my app starts, it will load all the classes that implement this trait.

```
trait Plugin {
  def init(config: Properties)
  def execute(parameters: Map[String, Array[String]])
}
```

In my learning of Scala, I've read that if I want to program in functional way, I should avoid using var. Here's my problem:
The init method will be called after the class being loaded. And probably I will want to use the values from the config parameter in the execute method.
How to store this without using a var? Is there a better practice to do what I want here?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more to programming in a functional way than just avoiding vars. One key concept is also to prefer immutable objects. In that respect your Plugin API is already breaking functional principles as both methods are only executed for their side-effects. With such an API using vars inside the implementation does not make a difference.

For an immutable plugin instance you could split plugin creation:

```
trait PluginFactory {
    def createPlugin (config: Properties): Plugin
}

trait Plugin {
    def execute ...
}
```

Example:

```
class MyPluginFactory extends MyPlugin {
  def createPlugin (config: Properties): Plugin = {
    val someValue = ... // extract from config
    new MyPlugin(someValue)
  }
}

class MyPlugin (someValue: String) extends Plugin {
  def execute ... // using someConfig
}
```

Comment: It seems to be a better way. But how the Plugin class will make use of the properties?

Comment: Is there any way to use he mixins dinamically?
Supose I have a Plugin1, Plugin2, PluginN
is there any way to instantiate a Plugin with Plugin1,Plugin2, PluginN?

Comment: Usually through constructor parameters, ideally extracting the relevant values already in the factory. I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `val`! It's basically the same thing, but the value of a `val` field cannot be modified later on. If you were using a class, you could write:

For example:

```
class Plugin(val config: Properties) {

  def init {
    // do init stuff...
  }

  def execute = // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, a `trait` cannot have class parameters. If you want to have a `config` field in your trait, you wont be able to set its value immediately, so it will have to be a `var`.

Comment: I've got an error:
trait MyPlugin extends Plugin{

  val configProperties: Properties

  override def init(config: Properties): Unit = {
    configProperties = config
  }

  override def execute(parameters: Map[String, Array[String]]): Unit = {}
}

Comment: Sorry, very true. You have to set the ``configProperties`` field immediately! I'll modify my answer to fix it.

Comment: @ACDias use var in place of val

Comment: so basically I'll have to create an abstract class instead of a trait?